# Laravel 5 - Upgrade to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I had a project on Laravel 5.1 and now I upgraded to 5.3.
All seems to work fine but I'm missing some "essentials" that were in the upgrade/change notes of 5.3 as the new routes structure.

It seems that my upgrade did not create those folders and as I tried to create them manually and also delete the old routes.php in App/Http, it didn't worked as expected.
It doesn't work at all....

How can I create the new folder structure in Laravel 5.3 as I need it for other plugins/extensions? Do I need to modify/create more than just the folder structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for future readers, you can avoid these silly gotchas while manually upgrading by using Shift to [automate upgrading your Laravel projects](https://laravelshift.com). **Full disclosure: I created Shift.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it manually. [Laravel Framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) and [Laravel project base](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) are two separate repositories. Updating your `composer.json` to use newest Laravel framework will only update its package in the `/vendor` directory.

Comment: do I need to register the new routes folder somewhere?

Comment: In Laravel 5.3, by default you just put your basic routes to /routes/web.php instead of /app/Http/routes.php.